# IE saveAs dialog - 'File Name' control doesnt have combo box(MRU list), instead has a edit ctrl - why?

Tags: internet-explorer, visual-c++

[image: why Edit control instead of Combo - any IE setting?]

IE automation in VC++ doesnt work in a specifi PC. I found that IE's saveAs dialog is little different than my other PC with same IE. Is there any IE seeting that brings Edit control instead of a Combo control.?! (as in the image)

Comment: Could you provide versions and screenshots?

Comment: OS Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise(64-bit), SP1, 
Internet Explorer(32-bit) 8.0.7601.17514

Comment: I guess security restrictions block some "info leak" vulnerability". "Thou shalt not see the MRU!"

Comment: yeah - what is that security restriction. any setting?

Comment: Sorry, no ideas, but using IE on a recent MS Server painfull.